# Angular 2+: In parent with multiple child components, list all grandchild1's followed by grandchild2's

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to list, both statically (and dynamically - but that's a different question), components in the following way. (this is useful both for tabs which we need their titles as templates to allow for buttons, custom formatting, etc, and also for lists of contents and other such things)

My parent component starts with a list of child components, and each child contains two different grand child components:

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <grandchild-1>child 1</grandchild-1>
    <grandchild-2>child 1 extended content</grandchild-2>
  </child>
  <child>
    <grandchild-1>child 2</grandchild-1>
    <grandchild-2>child 2 extended content</grandchild-2>
  </child>
</parent>
```

Now I want to first list all grandchild-1's (within a ul, and each in an li), followed by all grandchild-2's:

```
<ul>
  <li (click)="parentMethod()">child 1</li>
  <li (click)="parentMethod()">child 2</li>
</ul>
<div>child 1 extended content</div>
<div>child 2 extended content</div>
```

I can easily list the grandchild-2's by setting the parent's template to:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

and the child component's template to:

```
<div>
    <ng-content select="grandchild-2"></ng-content>
</div>
```

but can't seem to figure out how to do the prior list of the grandchild-1 components. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-38xf2q for full code listing of this (static) listing problem.

I've been playing around with `ng-template` (adding it around the `grandchild-1` component in the child component template) and `ng-container` (in a `<ul>` in the parent template, and iterating over child components, trying to add their `grandchild-1` templates). It seems like this should have such a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked it out (after trying for hours, and of course just after posting), but if someone has a better solution...

In the child template, create an `ng-template` around the `grandchild-1` content, so that the full child template html becomes:

```
<ng-template #granchild1TemplateRef>
  <ng-content select="grandchild-1"></ng-content>
</ng-template>
<div><ng-content select="grandchild-2"></ng-content></div>
```

Now in the child class, get a handle on this `TemplateRef`:

```
export class ChildComponent  {
  @ViewChild('granchild1TemplateRef') public Granchild1TemplateRef: TemplateRef<Grandchild1Component>;
}
```

Now we have a *`TemplateRef`* to the child's content, we can inject it into the list `ng-container`'s in the parent, so that the parent's full template html becomes:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let child of children">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="child.Granchild1TemplateRef"></ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

https://angular-zyas6r.stackblitz.io